# Which is the correct way to ensure you end up with an Array greater than 1 after Splitting?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I am currently doing a big project (by big I mean, many processes) where every millisecond I save means a lot (on the long run), so I want to make sure I am doing it the right way.

**So, what is the best way to ensure you will have an array greater than 1?**

- a) use indexOf(), then if result is different than -1, split()
- b) split (regardless if characters exist), then do stuff ONLY if the
  array.length is greater than 1
- c) another not listed above

Comment: Every *millisecond*? Where are you "saving" your data to?

Comment: Best way to tell is to profile it in Chrome/Safari developer tools, IE8,9 developer console, Firefox/Firebug.

Comment: Jared Farrish, I meant like, those milliseconds (after some thousands of loops) turn to 'seconds'

Comment: How about - getting rid of "_thousands of loops_" first of all ? ;)

Comment: c69, they all are 100% necessary. I spent hours and hours making the most efficient way, now the next step is to improve the splitting ;)

Comment: The only way to find out is to benchmark the different ways (http://jsperf.com/). I bet on the second one, though I don't think it makes much of a difference.

Comment: ampersand, done, added the 'greater than 1' part

Comment: If [`.split()`](http://jsfiddle.net/yH3QK/) will always return an array, even if there is no value to *split* on, why bother with `.indexOf()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/split-and-split-indexof), it appears that omitting `.indexOf()` is roughly 23% more efficient that including it over 500,000 iterations  (`11.67` vs. `8.95` operations per second):

**Without `indexOf()`**:

```
var str = "test";
for (var i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
    var test = str.split('.');
}
```

**With `.indexOf()`**:

```
var str = "test";
for (var i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
    if (str.indexOf('.')) {
        var test = str.split('.');
    } else {
        var test = str;
    }
}
```

http://jsperf.com/split-and-split-indexof

**EDIT**

Hmm... If the following line is:

```
if (str.indexOf('.') > -1)
```

http://jsperf.com/split-and-split-indexof-with-indexof-check

Or any other comparison, it's seemingly quite a bit faster (by about 69%).

The only reason I can think this is the case is that running `.split()` on every variable will perform two functions on each value (find, then separate), instead of just one when necessary. Note, this last part is just a guess.

Comment: using IndexOf like you did is very smart. I will start using it like that too (since I assume it is safe to use it that way due your reputation points). Thanks for teaching this new way (even if you didn't meant to) :)

Comment: Without knowing your exact use case, I would say you really don't need `.indexOf()`, and calling it will have an overhead (I think especially if you have a long string value). Since you'll get an array either way with `.split()`, I don't see why you can't just omit `.index()`.

Comment: @ogps92 - See my edit. Confusingly, once I actually tested the `.indexOf()` value against another value (`> -1`, for instance), with `.indexOf()` was quite a bit faster.

Comment: check this other version more similar of what I want it to do http://jsperf.com/split-and-split-indexof-with-indexof-check/2 (notice that if you 'split' and 'indexOf' by a char that don't exist on 'str', the performance switchs)

Comment: @ogps92 - Check this one out: http://jsperf.com/split-and-split-indexof-with-indexof-check/4 You'll probably not have a "definitive" answer without checking with real-world data.

Answer (score 0):

We can see that even when there is something to split the best results come from doing the indexOf test against a value.  Still the improvement is worse that the cases where 100% of items don't need a split.   Thus as you have more items needing to be split testing returns less benefit (as would be expected).    So it really depends on the use case since the extra code takes up memory and uses resources.

http://jsperf.com/split-and-split-indexof/2

Answer (score -1):

(b) is obviously more efficient than (a) because split uses the same logic as indexOf and that logic will not need to be repeated if there are indeed more than 2 elements. i cannot think of a more efficient way.

Comment: Using `.indexOf()` may be consistently *faster*: http://jsperf.com/split-and-split-indexof-with-indexof-check

Comment: `.length` is a property, which I don't think is always updated, so it isn't so reliable.

Comment: @vol7ron - Where is `.length` mentioned in this answer? Or is there something you're referring to?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: `b) split (regardless if characters exist), then do stuff ONLY if the` ***`array.length`*** `is greater than 1`

Comment: @vol7ron - Ah, I see. I attributed that to the OP's being too specific (since they would not necessarily need the `.length`).

Comment: Disregard the jsperf test refuting my answer -- its sole test string covers only the case where it does not split.  The OP's code will encounter examples of both types -- i. e. strings that do split into more than 1 and strings that do not. My answer recommending (b) considers both types of cases. For strings that do split into more than 1, not using indexOf() will clearly win. What the net balance will be depends on various factors (perhaps the jsperf fan can come up with a decent test case exercising a mix of the 2 types); my experience says to go without the indexOf for an overall win.